# In C#, How can i see if my dataset is empty?

Tags: c#, .net

I've used row.count recently to try and help me see if the dataset is empty, are there possibly other ways to tell if a dataset is empty? (More up to date 2022)

I tried Row.count and i've googled further but would love direct answers from people

Comment: Sometimes, there may be a difference between the dataset being null itself and having no rows.

Comment: try if (ds. HasChanges() & ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0){ return true;}else{return false;}

Comment: `DataSet`s don't have rows, they have `Tables` (which are `DataTable`s).  A `DataTable` has `Rows`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few methods to test the dataset and tables within:

```
Dataset ds;

if (ds != null) {}  //Check if Dataset is null.

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {}  //Check if Dataset has any tables.

if (ds.Tables.Contains("tableName")) {}  //Check if Dataset has a specific table name.

Datatable dt = ds.Tables["tableName"];  //Get the specific table.
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {}  //Check if specific table has rows.

if (dt.Columns.Contains("columnName")) {}  //Check if specific table has a specific column name.
```